# A name and notation for a category

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology

Is there a name and a standard notation for the category $C$ defined as follows:

- objects of $C$ are all small "objects" (small sets in ZF, because in ZF all objects are sets);
- morphisms of $C$ from $a$ to $b$ are all small functions such that $f(a)=b$.

Comment: How do you define composition?

Comment: @StefanPerko as composition of functions

Comment: How do you compose the function $f : \{1\}\to \{1\},x \mapsto x$, which is a morphism $1\to 1$ with the function $g : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2$, which is a morphism $1\to 1$? (What is $f\circ g$?)

Comment: @StefanPerko $g\circ f$ is the function with domain $\{1\}$ which maps $1$ to $1$

Comment: So what is the identity on $1$? It can't be $f$, since $g\circ f = f$.

Comment: @StefanPerko It is my error: This is not a category (it has no identites), but a precategory (a category without identities). But the essence of my question does not change.

Comment: I still (personally) don't understand how composition is defined. Saying "function composition" is not enough since there is no reason why two of these morphims need to be composable.

Comment: @StefanPerko Consider $f$ and $g$ as binary relations. Then the composition of $f$ and $g$ is the usual composition of binary relations $g\circ f$ (it is obviously also a function, that is a monovalued binary relation)

Comment: @porton: Ah, do you mean, as the morphisms of your pre-category are *small* binary relations ('partial functions') on the **class** $\rm{Set}$? Anyway, for me, it feels like a *dual* of something..

Comment: @StefanPerko: You're running into problems because you're trying to compose an element of $\hom(1,1)$ with an element of $\hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, which isn't well-defined. You're implicitly using a morphism $\hom(1, \mathbb{R})$ to make this well defined, but no such morphism exists in this category.

Comment: @Hurkyl One of us is misunderstanding the question: The second bulletpoint tells us nothing concrete about the domain and codomain of $f$ *in* $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: @StefanPerko: Ah, I see; I read it as "all small functions $a \to b$ such that..." where you read it as "all small functions whose domain contains $a$..."

Answer (score 0):

I would probably call this something like "the subcategory of epimorphisms in **Set**". If I were to use it a lot, especially with other categories, I would probably name it something like Epi(**Set**).